# How to Automatically run unit test (from MS test) and log result when commit on TFS ? [ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, tfs, mstest

I'm looking for automate Unit test (using MS TEST), when a developer commits his code on TFS.

I'm not sure it's possible ...

In a second time, I want to log on file, the result of the test unit execution, if you have a solution with VS.

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Try this: [Get started with continuous testing with TFS 2015 / 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-continuous-testing)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a **CI build** in TFS to build and run your Unit tests just like it mentioned in the comment above. The [Continuous integration (CI) build trigger](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#continuous-integration-ci) will make your build definition be queued when someone check in something.

When a build finishes, all the test results could be found in TFS web page and the test result file(.trx) also supports to download.

Comment: @BaptisteIbliiS Is there any feedback?